# Attempting to spawn processes in ruby returns NoMethod error

Tags: ruby

I am very new to ruby and I'm trying to spawn a process using the spawn command

but I encounter

```
undefined method `spawn' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

when I attempt to call spawn with a single argument.
I tried

```
sudo gem install spawn
```

which installed something but it returns the same error.

I'm using ruby version 1.8.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 which is what I got when I ran

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Can someone ofer some guidance?

Comment: did you require the spawn library? `require 'spawn'. Also if you paste more code, it's helpful.

Comment: I trie "ruby simple.rb -rlibrary spawn" . Same error :( .Should i do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently running Ruby version 1.8.7, Which was added in from 1.9.1.

The easiest way to managed your ruby version is via the tool called [RVM](http://rvm.io/)

**Downloading RVM (Do not sudo this command)**

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

**Then you'll need to add the location to sources(You'll probably need to reload your bash for rvm to work)**

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

**You can install your desired version like so(replace ruby_version with one you would like to install, eg 2.1.4)**

```
rvm install ruby_version
```

**To list the available version on your machine**

```
rvm list
```

**To use a version of ruby run**

```
rvm use ruby_version
```

If you have any trouble refere to the [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) website

Answer (score 2):

The [`spawn`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/spawn) API is available only on ruby version 1.9.1 and up...

Comment: How would I upgrade my ruby version?